# Using Aggregate to simulate .distinct() but with a find statement in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, set, aggregation-framework

I know .distinct() and the aggregation pipelines are different and are not mutually inter-operable.  However, I would like to use the aggregation pipeline to produce a return set like the .distinct() command, but where I get to use a find({query}) to filter the records first.

So, if in distinct, I can do:

```
> db.coll.distinct('institution.name')
[
"MySite",
"MySite2",
"Stack Overflow",
"Google",
..etc.
]
```

And for the aggregation I'd like to do, using a subset on params, where {"users": {$gt: 1000000}}'s.  So, I'd like a similar array output, finding all distinct names:

```
> db.coll.aggregate([ 
    {$group:{_id:{"users": {$gt: 1000000}}, array:{"institution.name"????}}}, 
]);
[
"Stack Overflow",
"Google",
..etc.
]
```

Comment: Have you looked at $addToSet?  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a query to distinct.  Use the following syntax:

```
> db.coll.distinct('institution.name',  {"users": {$gt: 1000000}} )
```

The correct syntax for aggregation framework would be:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$match:{"$users": {$gt: 1000000}},
    {$group:{
        _id:null, 
        array:{"$addToSet":"$institution.name"}
    }}, 
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to say exactly without seeing the structure of your collection, but it looks like you could get the answer you are looking for by using [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) :

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:{"$users": {$gt: 1000000}}, 
        array:{"$addToSet":"$institution.name"}
    }}, 
]);
```